# How can I calculate the following double integral?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

I want to solve the following integral:

$$\int_0^t x^{-2}\exp\left(-\frac{c_1}{x}\right)\int\limits_0^x y^{-2}\exp\left(-\frac{c_2}{y}\right) \exp\left(-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\max\left(\frac{c^k_1}{y},\frac{c^k_2}{x}\right)\right)dydx, $$

where $c_1$, $c_2$, $c^1_1, \ldots, c^n_1$ and $c^1_2, \ldots, c^n_2$ are arbitrary constants; Now this would be no problem if it was not for the last exponential term with the max in it;

What I understand is that for any $k \in 1, \ldots, n$ it holds that
$\max\left(\frac{c^k_1}{y},\frac{c^k_2}{x}\right)=\frac{c^k_1}{y}$ if $y\leq x \cdot c_1^k/c_2^k$ and $\frac{c^k_2}{x}$ otherwise;

Therefore, if $n=1$ then we could simply split the inner integral into two parts; If $n=2$, it would be still relatively easy; One would just split the inner integral into several parts;

However, if $n$ is fixed but unknown, I do not know how to solve the integral

Can anyone give me an idea/inspiration on how to continue from here?

Comment: Is $x\in(0,\infty)$?

Comment: the first integral has range from 0 to t - is that what you mean?

Comment: So the integral is$$\int_{\color{red}0}^{\color{red}t} \cdots \int_0^x \cdots \, dy \, dx \, ?$$You should include that in the question, and include whatever condition you might have on $t$. I was basically asking if $t\to\infty$.

Comment: You are right, I updated it - though if you do not write any limits in the integral, then it just means you are looking for the indefinite integral, so from that you can also easily deduct the integral from 0 to t